# Converting a list of lists of dictionaries to a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

What might be the best way of going about working with the data structure of a list of list of dictionaries like the one I'm working with:

```
       [[{'name': 'Export A Smooth'},
       {'filter': 'unfiltered'},
       {'number of cigarette': 25},
       {'nicotine content': 10.5},
       {'tar content': 15.0},
       {'menthol': False},
       {'king size': False},
       {'price': 18.99},
       {'units sold per week': 50},
       {'profits per week': 949.50}],

      [{'name': 'Export A Medium'},
       {'filter': 'white'},
       {'number of cigarette': 25},
       {'nicotine content': 10.0},
       {'tar content': 12.0},
       {'menthol': False},
       {'king size': False},
       {'price': 18.99},
       {'units sold per week': 39},
       {'profits per week': 740.61}],

      [{'name': 'Canadian Classics Select'},
       {'filter': 'brown'},
       {'number of cigarette': 25},
       {'nicotine content': 11.1},
       {'tar content': 11.0},
       {'menthol': True},
       {'king size': True},
       {'price': 19.09},
       {'units sold per week': 38},
       {'profits per week': 725.42}]]
```

and turn it into a structured table format:

| name | Filter | Number of Cigarettes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Export A Smooth | unfiltered | 25 |
| Export A Medium | white | 25 |
| Canadian Classics Select | brown | 20 |

I've tried a few different methods for getting the right table format and the **table format is correct** but there is a lot of **`NaN` values** that pop up for all the cigarettes except the **first one** (export smooth).

| unit | name | filter | profits per week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Export A Smooth | NaN | ... 900 | NaN |
| 2 | NaN | unfiltered | ... | NaN |
| 3 | NaN | NaN | ... | NaN |
| 4 | NaN | NaN | ... | NaN |
| 5 | NaN | NaN | ... | NaN |
| .. ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 155 | NaN | NaN | ... | NaN |
| 156 | NaN | NaN | ... | NaN |
| 157 | NaN | NaN | ... | NaN |
| 158 | NaN | NaN | ... | NaN |
| 159 | NaN | NaN | ... | 447.72 |

I've tried `pd.DataFrame(cig_list).stack().apply(pd.Series)` and `pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(ii) for ii in cigarettes])` as well as looping through the cigs and trying to pass them into the DataFrame in that way.

```
   cig_list_items = []
   for items in cig_list:
   for _ in items:
   cig_list_items.append(_)
   pd.DataFrame(cig_list_items)
```

They all return the same result so I figure there must be some issue with the way the dictionaries are formatted? My suspicion is that the dictionaries need to be rearranged so that they read more like this:

```
[[{'name': 'Export A Smooth'},
  {'name': 'Export A Medium'}
  {'name': 'Pall Mall Bold'}],


  [{'filter': 'unfiltered'},
  {'filter': 'white'}
  {'filter': 'regular'}]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since every entry is a individual dict, you can join them using list+dict comprehension:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{k: v for d in i for k, v in d.items()} for i in l])

print (df)

                       name      filter  number of cigarette  nicotine content  tar content  menthol  king size  price  units sold per week  profits per week
0           Export A Smooth  unfiltered                   25              10.5         15.0    False      False  18.99                   50            949.50
1           Export A Medium       white                   25              10.0         12.0    False      False  18.99                   39            740.61
2  Canadian Classics Select       brown                   25              11.1         11.0     True       True  19.09                   38            725.42
```

Answer (score 0):

let us assume your list of lists is in `lst` variable, then try this:

```
flat_list = [item for sublist in t for item in lst]

df = pd.json_normalize(flat_list)
```

First it flattens the list of lists into a list where each item is a dictionary. Then converts the whole thing into a pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

if you find coprehensions har to read heres whats going on inside:

```
newlist=[]
for i in data:
     newdict={}
     for j in i:
         for key,item in j.items():
             new_dict[key]=item
     newlist.append(new_dict)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(newlist)
```